# How to add drop event to Vuetify calendar <v-calendar>

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, drop, vcalendar

I need to drag an event from outside to v-calendar.

But, Vuetify does not have drop event.

How can I add drop event to Vuetify?

As you see in the below screenshot, I have two tasks above the calendar and I want to add them to the "Vuetify" calendar.

[image]

Comment: You can look into this issue which provides some ways to implement the drop functionality.
https://github.com/richardtallent/vue-simple-calendar/issues/103

Comment: you can use fullCalendar, it has all functionallity you need . https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: fullcalendar.io is so good but i need free one

Comment: github.com/richardtallent/vue-simple-calendar/issues/103  is so good thnx